# Selenium webdriver not connecting to proxy

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im facing a strange issue and thinking about reconfiguring the selenium webdriver libary. Before doing this im hoping to find a simpler answer here.
FYI: Im using python 2.7

I have 2 functions and 1 model:

This function is used to start the Firefox sessionr

```
def register_user():
    proxy_config = ProxyHandler.set_proxy()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy_config.proxy, firefox_profile=proxy_config.profile)
    driver.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
```

Next I am connecting to the proxy which works perfectly well. Im testing it with the ipify.org api. I also tried to remove this call since the proxy might be usable only once and it may disconnect after this call.

```
def set_proxy():
username = 'USENAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

entry = ('http://customer-%s:%s@pr.oxylabs.io:8000' %
         (username, password))

query = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': entry,
    'https': entry,
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': entry,
    'ftpProxy': entry,
    'sslProxy': entry,
    'noProxy': ''  # set this value as desired
})

proxy = urllib2.build_opener(query)

req = proxy.open("https://api.ipify.org?format=json").read()
j = json.loads(req)
ip = j['ip']
print ip

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https", ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", ip)
profile.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "X-Forwarded-For")
profile.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name1", "X-Client-IP")
profile.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", ip)
profile.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value1", ip)
profile.update_preferences()
prof = profile

return ProxyModel.ProxyModel(proxy, prof, ip)
```

And finally my model, which should be fine.

```
class ProxyModel:

def __init__(self, _proxy, _profile, _ip):
    self.proxy = _proxy
    self.profile = _profile
    self.ip = _ip
```

Is the selenium webdriver capable of opening a session with a urllib2.ProxyHandler instance set? Am I opening the webdriver instance correctly?
Any help is appreciated